# Slicing 3D numpy array using list of index

Tags: python, numpy, slice

The objective is to slice 3D array using list of index.

Here, the array is of shape `2,5,5`. For simplicity, let assume the index 0 to 4 label as `A,B,C,D,E`.

Assume we have 3d array as below

```py
array([[[44, 47, 64, 67, 67],
        [ 9, 83, 21, 36, 87],
        [70, 88, 88, 12, 58],
        [65, 39, 87, 46, 88],
        [81, 37, 25, 77, 72]],

       [[ 9, 20, 80, 69, 79],
        [47, 64, 82, 99, 88],
        [49, 29, 19, 19, 14],
        [39, 32, 65,  9, 57],
        [32, 31, 74, 23, 35]]], dtype=int64)
```

The index of interest is `[1,3,4]`. Again, we label this as B,D,E`. The expected output, when slicing the 3D array based on the index is as below

```py
array([[[83, 36, 87],
        [39, 46, 88],
        [37, 77, 72]],

       [[64, 99, 88],
        [32,  9, 57],
        [31, 23, 35]]], dtype=int64)
```

However, slicing the array as below

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2, 5, 5))
k=arr[:,(1,3,4),(1,3,4)]
```

does not produced the expect output.

In actual use case, the number of element to be sliced  is > 3 elements (> B,D,E). Sorry for the lack of correct terminology used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which is similar structure to your `arr[:,idx,idx]` but using `np.ix_()`. Do read the [documentation for np.ix()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).-

```
idx = [1,3,4]
ixgrid = np.ix_(idx,idx)
arr[:,ixgrid[0],ixgrid[1]]
```

```
array([[[83, 36, 87],
        [39, 46, 88],
        [37, 77, 72]],

       [[64, 99, 88],
        [32,  9, 57],
        [31, 23, 35]]])
```

---

#### Explanation

**What you are WANT to do is extract a mesh from the last 2 axes of the array. But what you are doing is extract exact indexes from each of the 2 axes.**

- When you use `arr[:,(1,3,4),(1,3,4)]`, you are essentially asking for `(1,1)`, `(3,3)` and `(4,4)` from the two matrices `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`

[image]

- What you need is to extract a mesh. This can be achieved with `np.ix_` and the magic of broadcasting.

[image]

If you ask for ...

```
[[1],
 [3],   and   [1,3,4]
 [4]]
```

... which is what the `np.ix_` constructs, you broadcast the indexes and instead ask for a cross product between them, which is `(1,1), (1,3), (1,4), (3,1), (3,3)...` etc.

Hope that clarifies why you get the result you are getting and how you can actually get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Advanced indexing expects all dimensions to be indexed explicitly. What you're doing here is grabbing the elements at coordinates `(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4)` in each array along axis 0.

### The solution

What you need to do is this instead:

```py
idx = (1, 3, 4)  # the indices of interest
arr[np.ix_((0, 1), idx, idx)]
```

Where `(0, 1)` corresponds to the first two arrays along axis 0.

Output:

```py
array([[[83, 36, 87],
        [39, 46, 88],
        [37, 77, 72]],

       [[64, 99, 88],
        [32,  9, 57],
        [31, 23, 35]]], dtype=int64)
```

As shown above, `np.ix_((0, 1), idx, idx))` produces an object which can be used for advanced indexing. The `(0, 1)` means that you're explicitly selecting the elements from the arrays `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. If you have a more general 3D array of shape `(n, m, q)` and want to grab the same subarray out of every array along axis 0, you can use

```py
np.ix_(np.arange(arr.shape[0]), idx, idx))
```

As your indices. Note that `idx` is repeated here because you wanted those specific indices but in general they don't need to match.

### Generalizing

More generally, you can slice and dice however you want like so:

```py
In [1]: arrays_to_select = (0, 1)

In [2]: rows_to_select = (1, 3, 4)

In [3]: cols_to_select = (1, 3, 4)

In [4]: indices = np.ix_(arrays_to_select, rows_to_select, cols_to_select)

In [5]: arr[indices]
Out[5]:
array([[[83, 36, 87],
        [39, 46, 88],
        [37, 77, 72]],

       [[64, 99, 88],
        [32,  9, 57],
        [31, 23, 35]]], dtype=int64)
```

Let's consider some other shape:

```py
In [4]: x = np.random.randint(0, 9, (4, 3, 5))

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([[[1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
        [3, 5, 1, 4, 3],
        [1, 8, 1, 4, 2]],

       [[1, 6, 8, 2, 8],
        [0, 0, 4, 2, 3],
        [8, 5, 6, 2, 5]],

       [[4, 4, 8, 6, 0],
        [3, 0, 1, 2, 8],
        [0, 8, 2, 4, 3]],

       [[7, 8, 8, 1, 4],
        [5, 7, 4, 8, 5],
        [7, 5, 5, 3, 4]]])

In [6]: rows = (0, 2)

In [7]: cols = (0, 2, 3, 4)
```

By using those `rows` and `cols`, you'll be grabbing the subarrays composed of all the elements from columns 0 through 4, from only the rows 0 and 2. Let's verify that with the first array along axis 0:

```py
In [8]: arrs = (0,)  # A 1-tuple which will give us only the first array along axis 0

In [9]: x[np.ix_(arrs, rows, cols)]
Out[9]:
array([[[1, 2, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 4, 2]]])
```

Now suppose you want the subarrays produced by `rows` and `cols` of only the first and last arrays along axis 0. You can explicitly select `(0, -1)`:

```py
In [10]: arrs = (0, -1)

In [11]: x[np.ix_(arrs, rows, cols)]
Out[11]:
array([[[1, 2, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 4, 2]],

       [[7, 8, 1, 4],
        [7, 5, 3, 4]]])
```

If, instead, you want that same subarray from *all* the arrays along axis 0:

```py
In [12]: arrs = np.arange(x.shape[0])

In [13]: arrs
Out[13]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [14]: x[np.ix_(arrs, rows, cols)]
Out[14]:
array([[[1, 2, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 4, 2]],

       [[1, 8, 2, 8],
        [8, 6, 2, 5]],

       [[4, 8, 6, 0],
        [0, 2, 4, 3]],

       [[7, 8, 1, 4],
        [7, 5, 3, 4]]])
```